# Is Nietzsche's proposed etymology of "bonus" (good) correct?

Tags: etymology, philosophy

In the first treatise of *On the Genealogy of Morality*, §5, Nietzsche proposes the following derivation of *bonus* (good):

> I believe I may interpret the Latin *bonus* as "the warrior": assuing that I am correct in tracing *bonus* back to an older *duonus* (compare *bellum = duellum = duen-lum*, in which that *duonus* seems to me to be preserved). *Bonus* accordingly as man of strife, of division (*duo*), as man of war--one sees what it was about a man that constituted his "goodness" in ancient Rome. (translation by Clark and Swensen)

Obviously, a lot of important etymological scholarship by more level heads has happened since 1887. **Is Nietzsche's proposed etymology for *bonus* plausible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It is plausible that *bonus* is related to *bellum/duellum*

Nietzsche is correct about *bonus* coming from an older form starting with *du-*: not only is this consistent with known Latin sound changes, we apparently even have inscriptional evidence of forms starting with *duon-* and *duen-* in Old Latin. The reconstructed pronunciation of *du-* here is /dw/.

As Alex B. said in a comment, Michiel de Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary of Latin* (2008) says that "The best etymology for *duellum* so far has been proposed by Pinault 1987, who posits a dim. **duenelo-* to *bonus*".

#### But modern linguists don't agree with the idea that *bonus* originally meant "the warrior"

However, Nietzsche's implication of an etymological connection between *bellum/duellum* and *duo* seems to be regarded less favorably by de Vaan, who says that the PIE source of *bonus* is unclear, and who says that the use of the form *duellum* with three syllables in pronunciation in later poets "may be either the result of **folk etymology** with *duo*, or a regular development".

And it seems that even though modern sources support a connection between *bonus* and *bellum,* they view the semantic connection as developing in the opposite direction: rather than an older word for *warrior* coming to mean *good,* de Vaan suggests that *bonus* (*duenos*) originally meant *good,* and the derivative *bellum* (*duellum*) was euphemistically used to describe war.

Answer (score 11):

This etymology is not accepted by modern scholars, though the ultimate origin of "bonus" is contested. I cannot get de Vaan to scan properly, but here is Walde:

> **bonus** „gut“, altlat. *duonus*, noch älter *Duenos* (nicht damit ablautend; vgl. Thurneysen KZ. XXXV, 204, Pedersen KZ. XXXVI, 91), vgl. auch *bene, bellus*: nach Darmesteter De conjug. latini verbi dare (1876), 26 ff. , Osthoff MU. IV, 370 ptc. auf *-eno-* zur Wurzel von ai. *dúvaḥ* n. „Gabe, Ehrerweisung“, *durasyáti* „ehrt, verehrt, erkennt an, belohnt“, *duvasyú-ḥ, duvōyú-ḥ* „verehrend, ehrerbietig“, wozu auch lat. ***beāre*** „beglücken, erquicken“, ***beātus*** „selig, glücklich“ ; hierher nach Wood Mod. Philology IV, 499 als idg. **du̯ei-to-* vermutlich auch mnd. *twīden* „willfahren, gewähren, bewilligen, erhören“, mhd. *zwīden* ds., md. *getwedic* „zahm, willfährig“, vgl. auch as. *tu(g)iđon* „gewähren“, ags. *tygđian, tīđian* ds.; die Bed. „durch Gaben, durch Beschenkung ehren oder erfreuen“ (woraus die Bed. von ital. **du̯-ei̯ō, *du̯-enos* sich leicht ergibt) ist der Hirt'schen (IF. XXI, 169ff.) Anknüpfung der Sippe an alat. *duim* usw. „ich möge geben“ (s. *dō*; er führt idg. **dō-, *dōu̯-* auf älteres **dou̯e-* zurück) günstig. Sehr fraglich ist Zugehörigkeit von *dautia, lautia*, s. d.
>
> Wenig ansprechend ist Fröhdes BB. IX, 111, Ficks I<sup>4</sup>, 457, II<sup>4</sup>, 150 (ebenso Prellwitz Gr. Wb. unter δύναμαι) Verbindung von *bonus* mit einer Wz. **dū-:*deu̯ā-* „stark, fest“ in gr. *δύναμαι*.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a text transcription for those of us that have visual impairments that make it difficult to read text in an image? It would also make the text searchable.

Comment: de Vaan literally says this (s.v. bellum): "The best etymology for *duellum* [i.e. Old Latin for bellum - A.B.] so far has been proposed by Pinault 1987, who posits a dim. *duenelo- to bonus."

Comment: To expand on @AlexB.'s comment, de Vaan's explanation of the putative semantic link is this: "If *duenelo- meant 'quite good, quite brave', its use in the context of war (bella acta, bella gesta) could be understood as a euphemism, ultimately yielding a meaning 'action of valour, war' for the noun bellum". To me this sounds rather strained, especially given that de Vaan himself says of bellus (s.v. bonus) that it "was originally used to refer to women and children; it was applied to men only ironically".

Comment: @TKR I’m afraid you completely misunderstood de Vaan (or, rather, him reporting Pinault). Of course, it makes sense for **a diminutive** to be applied ironically back then, when women and children weren’t primarily engaged in warfare.

Comment: @AlexB. I understand the argument perfectly well -- it just strikes me as farfetched.

Comment: @TKR let’s agree to disagree then. :)

Comment: @AlexB. Certainly. It's always hard to know how to evaluate such things.

Comment: An English translation would be appreciated for those of us who don't speak German; I'd translate it myself but I'm afraid I'd miss a nuance.

Comment: @Draconis. I would be easier to copy out de Vaan's English if anyone has the energy to do so.

Comment: @fdb Alas, I don't have my own copy. But I'll stop by the library when I have a chance.

Comment: @Draconis and fdb, TKR and I have already shared the most relevant parts from de Vaan. "The best etymology for duellum so far has been proposed by Pinault 1987, who posits a dim. * duenelo- to bonus. If * duenelo- meant 'quite good, quite brave', its use in the context of war (bella acta, bella gesta) could be understood as a euphemism, ultimately yielding a meaning 'action of valour, war' for the noun bellum."

Comment: @Draconis and fdb, another quote from de Vaan (s.v. bonus): "Bellus reflects a dim. * duenelos > * duenlos > * duellos > * bellos. The dim. meaning is the reason why bellus was originally used to refer to women and children; it was applied to men only ironically. The meaning '(little) good (one)' still shines through in Varro in quo Graeci belliores quam Romani nostri 'at which the Greeks are better than our Romans', and Nonius belliores 'meliores'."

Answer (score -2):

The logic is sound: du = du, and duellum - du = ellum, much in the same way that du = du, and duonus - du = onus. Now in both cases where b = d, the results are the same: bonus and bellum.

Let's not ignore the consistency of the 'goodness of war' being implied in the etymology of both words.

reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin

Initial *dw- (attested in Old Latin as du-) becomes b-, thus compensating for the dearth of words beginning with *b in PIE:

Comment: *bellum/duellum* "war" is cognate with Greek *duh* "agony", while *bellus* "beautiful" comes from an old diminutive of *bonus/duenos*. They're not related. And a single word's analogy isn't a solid argument: as Brian pointed out, *bos* "cow" ≠ *duos* "two".

Comment: This is a little silly: the unstated premise is that, "If a subset of letters behaves in a certain way for one word, it behaves in the same way for all words." Considering that *optumus* is a variant spelling of *optimus*, you would need to claim that all i's in Latin can be replaced by u's. It's a clear *reductio ad absurdum*.

Comment: @Draconis why do you think that bellum (OL duellum) and bonus (OL duenos) are not related?

Comment: @AlexB. The etymology I've heard is that _duellum_ is from PIE _*d-h₂w_ "destroy" (> AGrk _δύη_ "agony") while _duenos_ is from PIE _*d-w_ "revere" (> Lat _beāre_ "bless"). But I wouldn't be surprised if de Vaan has something newer/more accurate.

Comment: @Dracnois -  I'm sorry, but they are related.  Bellum is the vocative of both 'war' and 'pretty' in old latin, however one of them gender neutral.  Bellum ("war") is the Inflection of bellus (“pretty”) - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bellum

Comment: @Dracnois -  (continued). But more importanlty, Nietzsche was pointing out,  they can both be traced back to the origination root 'duo' which is referencing conflict.

Comment: @brianpck  -  what's "silly" about that perfection of logic?  It is commonly accepted logic.  Please refer to Wikipedia's History of Latin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin

Initial *dw- (attested in Old Latin as du-) becomes b-, thus compensating for the dearth of words beginning with *b in PIE: 

So there is a clear reductio ad absurdum in here, but it's not this.

Comment: Comments are not meant for extended discussion. Octavian, your conclusions were challenged, and the best response is to back up your answer by editing to add sources. For a free discussion environment, consider [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm). In case something seems out of order or there are questions, anything related to the functions of this site should be taken to [our meta](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/).